# You are using a picture of a window well cover from my website with out my permission

Tags: discussion

I have not given you permission to use my photo. You have not mentioned where the picture came from. Please remove the photo from your website

Comment: In order for this to be actionable by the moderators, you need to indicate where the alleged copyright violation occurs. Please [edit] this post to include links to the page(s) where you find copyrighted material.

Comment: [Upon reviewing the site in question] there certainly are pics there which match pics in questions and/or answers here. But a google image search on those pics shows them on other sites too, so it's not immediately obvious that any of these are in fact Ken's copyrighted pics.

Comment: @brhans I've removed links to the site in question because it's not clear to me this isn't a spam post trying to get links to their site for SEO.

Comment: Ken, please file a DMCA report via the contact form on the site. For individual images, site mods and other users should not be removing content that is not explicitly plagiarizing of another site.

Comment: @BMitch the link in question is still on the main site, and I agree I suspect it’s a poor SEO attempt (poor because he didn’t create an actual link)

Comment: The link on the main site leads to this question.  That's standard for migrated questions.  Do we want to get it deleted in this case?

Comment: If someone has a copyright complaint, accusing them of linkspamming might violate our new "be nice" policy, especially when they abstained from making the link hot.  *A linkspammer would know how to make the link hot.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a false claim by the complaining vendor.  See answer.

Comment: I'm VTC because this is what email and lawyers are for.

Answer (score 3):

The only image from a post I could find that appears to match one on this vendor's website is this one from [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/143408/window-well-cover-for-boman-kemp-egress):

[image]

I used TinEye rather than Google to look for matching images.  TinEye isn't as good, but it found 120 matches.  So apparently the OP copied an image of the same type of window well cover rather than take a snapshot of their own cover.

Here is the image from the complaining vendor's website:

[image]

The bottom and left are cropped and the color is washed out.  The OP here could not have used the vendor's image because the OP's contains content that the vendor's image does not.

This is not the vendor's original, copyrighted image.  It does not belong to the vendor, the vendor is not using his own original image, and the vendor has no copyright on it.  In fact, the vendor's image is a crude copy of one from somewhere else, because most of the images found by TinEye are more complete and better images.